# Why aren't my Leaflet Icons appearing?

Tags: javascript, url, leaflet

I am trying to lay icons with images over my leaflet map, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: iconUrl not set in Icon options (see the docs).


...tIconUrl(t);if(!i){if("icon"===t)throw new Error("iconUrl not set in Icon option...
```

I don't understand why it is saying I don't have the url set.  Here is how I set up the code:

```
    var OfferIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {           
            iconSize:     [38, 95],
            shadowSize:   [50, 64],
            iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
            shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
        }
    });

    var iconName = json["offer_" + id + "_iconname"];
    // this is returning the correct file name



    var offerIcon = new OfferIcon(
            {
                iconUrl: iconName,
                name : name,
                id: id,
                value: value
            });
            L.marker([latitude, longitude], {icon: offerIcon}).addTo(markers).bindPopup(name);
        }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried on http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://plnkr.co/. The excerpt you show is not enough to help.The only thing that looks strange is that you have 2 variables called offericon.

Comment: I think it's just a case of missing `.png` or `.jpg` at the end of the icon url.

Comment: @IvanSanchez  That's not it, I printed the url and it has jpg/png at the end.  It is a full path however ("C:/django/.../static/media/images/").  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it should be either an absolute path to icon at your webserver (http://myserver.domain/static/media/images/icon.png) or relative path from server root (/static/media/images/icon.png)/

Comment: @Someone   I don't know if this helps, but I created a jsfiddle for this with the only difference being that I reference an online png for the icon url, and as you can see it works.  https://jsfiddle.net/dvdjsph/v30vL109/

Apparently there is a problem with retrieving the files from my hard drive.